# Ruby on rails server error with "rails s"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Everytime I input "rails s" into the command prompt I get this:

```
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sql
ite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'

        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
        from C:/users/202378/desktop/hello_world/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'

        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any help? thanks

Comment: Post code on line from C:/users/202378/desktop/hello_world/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>' but it looks mostly like a dependency missing. Also you are developing on windows which create a lot of issues (and slowdown). I tried windows, with ruby is too slow, I definitely suggest you to virtualize a distro like xubuntu.

Comment: Did your `bundle install` succeed?

Comment: yes it did, only stops when i put that command

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `sqlite3/sqlite3_native`. This is likely due to missing header or source files for sqlite3 in your win32 environment.